# How to show html string on UIWebview in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am making an app in which I am getting HTML string from web service. And now when I show this data on web view then facing some problem to show that data like -
HTML string from web service which I am getting is

```
<span style=\"color:#F00\">&lt;div align=\"left\"&gt;Highlights of latest deal&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</span>
```

and when I show this data on web view then output is

```
<div align="left"> Highlights of latest deal<br></div>
```

which are in red color. But I want output like "Highlights of latest deal" in red color. So can you suggest how to use these html tag to show data in proper format.

EDIT :-

Current code :-

```
[my_webview loadHTMLString:my_string baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: what is your current code?

Comment: [my_webview loadHTMLString:my_string baseURL:nil];

Answer (score 5):

You need to format string before loading it as-

Make my_string mutable first if not.

```
[my_string replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&gt;" withString:@">" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [self length])];
[my_string replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;" withString:@"<" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [self length])];
```

and load it with following code

```
[my_webview loadHTMLString:my_string baseURL:nil];
```